# Translate to multiple languages

Tags: translation

Is there a service that allows the simultaneous translation to multiple languages?

For example I would type in a word and get it translated to the 20 most common languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nice Translator](http://nicetranslator.com) do just that.
50+ langages available.

Answer (score 0):

Nice translator uses Google translate. If you want to try with a similar tool that uses yandex, try [Neno](http://neno-translate.com/)